# execute synchronous event in Node.js through shell command

Tags: node.js, protractor, spawn

Hello I am writing `tests in Protractor`, and I want to do some database Restore in the `conf.js` and I am doing it through `spawn` in `Node.Js` project using `node shell command`.

The code does works properly and restores the database. But the main issue is it works as async and the main thread does not wait for the restoration to get completed.

Here is my code.

```
var dbServer = '(local)';
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        spawn('sqlcmd', ['-S', dbServer, '-i', 'resources/databaseRestore.sql'] ,function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
            console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            }
        });
```

Can I wait for this function to get executed before any other work ? I have seen some of the example for `require('fs')` but not sure how to get this implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Node 0.12, which has been released just a little while ago, includes sync variants of the `child_process` functions. So If you can use 0.12, using `spawnSync()` instead of `spawn()` would do the trick. If you go this route, beware that spawnSync doesn't take a callback and instead returns an object `stdout`, `stdin` and `error` properties (among others). For more detail, check out the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options).

If using node 0.12 is not an option, you can wait for the process you spawned to exit and then continue executing the rest of your code. `spawn()` returns a child object, which emits an event when the child process finishes.

```
var child = spawn(...);
child.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
    //code and signal might tell you if the process was succesful.
    continueWithMainLogic();
});
```

BTW, to my knowledge the `spawn()` command does not take a callback, so in your example, that callback function will never get called. `exec()` does take a callback like the one in your example, which gets called after the process it spawned ends. So when using `exec()`, you can use that callback instead of the exit even handler.